# Find Coordinates of all html links

Tags: javascript, jquery, heatmap

Im using [Heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) to plot out a heatmap of the most clicked links. I have data containing the link url, and the number of clicks, but heatmap.js requires the coordinates of the link to display the data point. What would be the best approach to get the coordinates of each link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the position of the links using [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). The position given by `.offset()` is relative to the document, which means `0,0` would be the top left of the page.

```
//Attach a click handler to all links
$('body').on('click','a', function(event){

  //then get their offsets
  var coords = $(this).offset();
  var x = coords.left;
  var y = coords.top;
});
```